# How to apply animation conditionally?

Tags: angularjs, animate.css

In angularjs, inside a directive:

I have this array of animate.css animations:

```
['fadeIn','BounceInLeft'...]
```

And i have the following html:

```
<div ng-repeat="opt in quest.opts" ng-show="showBtns" class="animated" ng-class='getRandomClass()'>
```

1) How can i do something like this, so in every ng-repeat, a new animation from   the list will be applied to that div?

2)Can i make them 1 after another when they animate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $index to fetch the actual animation strings:

```
var animateArray = ['fadeIn', 'BounceInLeft', ... ]
<div ng-repeat="opt in quest.opts" ... class="animateArray[$index]" ...
```

This will apply each animation in order. If the array is say length 7 you can use a modulo to make it go back to the start:

```
var animateArray = ['fadeIn', 'BounceInLeft', ... ]
<div ng-repeat="opt in quest.opts" ... class="animateArray[$index % 7]" ...  // repeats after 7th element
```

If you want to make it random then generate a random number up to the length of the array on every loop run:

```
var randomInt(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}
var animateArray = ['fadeIn', 'BounceInLeft', ... ]
<div ng-repeat="opt in quest.opts" ... class="animateArray[randomInt(7)]" ...  // repeats after 7th element
```

Comment: And when i meant one after another, i meant finish one animation and then do the other one...sorry if i wasn't that clear

Comment: That is trickier. You need to know when the last animation ended, or exactly how long the animations lasted. $animate provides a function .then for you to trigger things when one animation has ended. for many, that is hard